# Erro ao iniciar Spring Boot com Tomcat 9.0.21

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, deploy

**Situação:** Tenho uma aplicação implementada com **Spring Boot** e preciso fazer deploy no Tomcat (v9.0.21).

**Problema:** Gerei o pacote .war normalmente e fiz o deploy.
Inicio a aplicação normalmente, porém, logo em seguida a aplicação é restartada, como a primeira vez o start foi com sucesso, na segunda vez dá erros de portas já usadas e a aplicação é derrubada.

Artefatos:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.mensagem</groupId>
    <artifactId>mensagem</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api-mensagem</name>
    <description>Websocket server de mensagens</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.corundumstudio.socketio</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-socketio</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**SpringBootApplication.java**

```java
package br.com.mensagemwebsocket;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MensagemApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MensagemApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MensagemApplication.class);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
#server.port=8088

#server.address=192.168.0.45
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

## DEV
# Connection url for the database "dbacacio"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbacacio

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Detalhe, não uso ```spring-boot-devtools```

Comment: como você fez isso: "Gerei o pacote .war normalmente e fiz o deploy."? quais comandos executou?

Comment: "logo em seguida a aplicação é restartada,", por que? você restartou? ela reinicia sozinha? mas isso foi implementado por você ou ela faz isso sozinha sem motivo?

Comment: @danilo Fiz o build (.war) usando o maven (clean install)

Comment: Só pra eu entender melhor, você está colocando o .war gerado dentro do tomcat? Se sim, tudo isso está local? Você alterou a porta do tomcat ou da sua aplicação no .properties?

Comment: Ela restarta sozinha, na verdade esse é problema.... inicia uma vez de boa e do nada ela reinicia. Nessa reiniciada começa a dar erros de porta.

Comment: @CaioAugustoPapai Eu envio o .war pelo "Tomcat Web Application Manager" em "WAR file to deploy". Sim, tudo isso é no meu loca. Quanto a porta do Tomcat está no 8080 e na minha aplicação não configurei porta nenhuma.

Comment: Vou colocar meu properties aqui.

Comment: Por que motivo ela restarta sozinha? Sugiro verificar seu `catalina.out` para identificar problemas. De qualquer forma,  se a porta já está sendo utilizada, quer dizer que o processo pode ter parado de funcionar (motivo do restart) e não liberou os recursos. Vale a pena verificar o que exatamente está em execução ocupando a porta.

Comment: Conforme abaixo achei a solução! Valeus!!!

Answer (score 1):

Achei a solução... nossa, que bom, depois de analisar códigos, inspirar nos comentários de vocês achei o problema.

Tinha uma classe **ServeletInitializer** que extende **SpringBootServletInitializer**.

Ai estava o problema. Removi essa classe e tudo rodou lindo conforme deveria ser. Estranho é que pelo Eclipse não dava esse erro, mas tudo bem.

Tive a intuição de remover essa classe, que nem sei porque havia colocado, quando vi essa parte do log apresentado no console.

Obrigado a todos pelas sugestões!!!

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTJct.jpg
```